# @google-cloud/vision npm package Issue

Tags: npm-install, google-cloud-vision

Unable to install **@google-cloud/vision** npm package on Raspberry Pi.

#### npm-log:

```
54 error git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/vision Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-google-cloud-vision-41bc45c9'...
54 error git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/vision Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
54 error git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/vision Permission denied (publickey).
54 error git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/vision fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
54 error git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/vision
54 error git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/vision Please make sure you have the correct access rights
54 error git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/vision and the repository exists.
55 silly lockFile 41bc45c9-t-github-com-google-cloud-vision git@github.com:google-cloud/vision
56 silly lockFile 41bc45c9-t-github-com-google-cloud-vision git@github.com:google-cloud/vision
57 silly lockFile d5a09ed3-google-cloud-vision google-cloud/vision
58 silly lockFile d5a09ed3-google-cloud-vision google-cloud/vision
59 error addLocal Could not install google-cloud/vision
60 error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'google-cloud/vision'
61 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
61 error including the npm and node versions, at:
61 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
62 error System Linux 4.14.79-v7+
63 error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "@google-cloud/vision"
64 error cwd /home/pi/voiceplatformtesting
65 error node -v v8.11.1
66 error npm -v 1.4.21
67 error path google-cloud/vision
68 error syscall stat
69 error code ENOENT
70 error errno -2
71 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all start by upgrading all your packages:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade    
sudo apt-get update
```

- Try again!
- Make sure your pi is connected to the internet, because your error is saying your permission to the repository (for downloading the package) is denied

If this doesn't work try the following (it could be an ssh issue):

```
sudo chown -R pi /home/pi/.ssh
chmod -R u=rw,go= /home/pi/.ssh
```

After that copy relevant parts of `[my user]/.ssh/config to /home/pi/.ssh/config`.

Last but not least you can generate a new ssh key:

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa
```